Bug in Idea suggestion for JPA efficient hashCode?
When you annotate some JPA Entity with Lombok:
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Person {

IntelliJ Idea will show a suggestion that it is not optimal:

Using @EqualsAndHashCode for JPA entities is not recommended. It can
cause severe performance and memory consumption issues.

And it generates the following code:
@Override
public final boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (this == object) return true;
    if (object == null) return false;
    Class<?> oEffectiveClass = object instanceof HibernateProxy ? ((HibernateProxy) object).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getPersistentClass() : object.getClass();
    Class<?> thisEffectiveClass = this instanceof HibernateProxy ? ((HibernateProxy) this).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getPersistentClass() : this.getClass();
    if (thisEffectiveClass != oEffectiveClass) return false;
    ConfigAudit that = (ConfigAudit) object;
    return getId() != null && Objects.equals(getId(), that.getId());
}

@Override
public final int hashCode() {
    return this instanceof HibernateProxy ? ((HibernateProxy) this).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getPersistentClass().hashCode() : getClass().hashCode();
}

I just noticed that the hashCode() is actually called on the class and not on the object. Is this bug?
Javadoc:

If two objects are equal according to the equals method, then calling
the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same
integer result.


Are you actually using a HashSet<Person>?

Also, what exactly do you mean with it being called on the class?

See: getClass().hashCode().

What is calling that? Can you show a concrete example?

https://jpa-buddy.com/guides/best-practices-and-common-pitfalls-of-using-lombok-with-jpa/

Yes, this was made intentionally - with this hashCode() implementation entities are grouped by classes and then can be compared by equals(). More details in this article https://jpa-buddy.com/blog/hopefully-the-final-article-about-equals-and-hashcode-for-jpa-entities-with-db-generated-ids/
